# Is it possible to use Che Theia plugin extensions with java projects?

Tags: java, eclipse-che, theia

Is it possible to use Che Theia plugin extensions (Che 7) with java projects?
For example is it possible to add custom menu or view using java projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my analysis its not possible to use Che Theia plugin extensions with java projects since the API is wrote in typescript.
Please refer :- https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/17461